# Found unparsable section: 'EXECUTE IMMEDIATE\n ...' sqlfuff?

Tags: google-bigquery, sqlfluff

I'm using sqlfluff to check the sql code formatting.
conf of sqlfluff are here :

```
    sqlfluff = "^0.13.2"
    [tool.sqlfluff]
    sql_file_exts = [
    ".sql",
    ]
    [tool.sqlfluff.core]
    dialect = "bigquery"
    rules = "L001,L002,L003,L004,L005,L006,L008,L009,L010,L012,L013,L015,L016,L018,L019,L020,L022,L023,L024,L025,L035,L036,L037,L038,L039,L040,L041,L045,L046,L048,L049,L050,L051,L052,L053,L061,L063"
```

I have a sql query that uses EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (dynamic bigquery sql)

```html
DECLARE
  c_c string;
DECLARE
  ps ARRAY<string>;
DECLARE
  p_cc string;
DECLARE
  d_cc string;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
  `dataset.table` ( A STRING,
    B STRING,
    C STRING,
    D STRING,
    F STRING,
    E STRING,
    G STRING,
    H STRING,
    E STRING,
    J timestamp,
    K INT64 ) PARTITION BY
  RANGE_BUCKET(K, GENERATE_ARRAY(0,100,1));
SET
  c_c="code1";
SET
  ps = ["project-code1",
  "project-code2",
  "project-code3",
  "project-code4",
  "project-code5",
  "project-code6"];
SET
  p_cc = (
  WITH
    ps_cte AS (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      UNNEST(ps) ps
    WHERE
      ps LIKE CONCAT('%-', c_c))
  SELECT
    ps
  FROM
    ps_cte);
SET
  d_cc = CONCAT(p_cc,".sales_",c_c,".");
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  FORMAT( """ 
  CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE temp_table AS
SELECT
    cols
FROM
     `%ssat_table` sc
 """,d_cc)
```

:

when I want to apply sqlfluff lint :

```
  poetry run sqlfluff lint query.sql
```

it gives:

```
   L:  47 | P:   1 |  PRS | Line 47, Position 1: Found unparsable section: 'EXECUTE
                   | IMMEDIATE\n FORMAT( """ \n CREAT...'
```

why sqlfluff don't know execute immediate ? is there any solution?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed? having similar issues